A way to handle multiple request content types and model list of json objects in FastAPI
I would to use content negotiation for proper JSON representation.
For example, I would like to have three types of HEADER ACCEPTANCE as follows

Accept:application/vnd.api.summarized+json
Accept:application/vnd.api.complete+json
Accept:application/vnd.api.extended+json

At this time, I would like to set up a List for each of the models. How should I express List in schema?
@router.get("/",
            summary="Get Items",
            description="",
            responses={                
                status.HTTP_200_OK: {
                    "description": "OK",
                    "content": {
                        "application/vnd.api.summarized+json": {
                            "schema": ItemSummarized.model_json_schema()
                        },
                        "application/vnd.api.complete+json": {
                            "schema": Item.model_json_schema()
                        },
                        "application/vnd.api.extended+json": {
                            "schema": {
                                "$ref": "#/components/schemas/Item"
                            }
                        },
                    },
                    "model": List[Item]
                }
            })
def read_items(

Could someone please help me?
